# Background user location when app is terminated/suspended

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I've been trying to figure out how to get the user's location when the app is terminated like how the app Moves does it. The only way I know of doing so is with Significant Location Changes. However with significant location changes, the app only gets woken up either every 500 meters and only if it has been around 5 minutes past the last update.

According to Apple:

> Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.

In the Moves app, even with the app is terminated, it is able to retrieve the user's location very accurately without having much drainage in battery. It also doesn't seem to have background location turned on as it's reason in the battery usage list only shows "Background Activity". So I'm wondering how an app like Moves is doing this. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can register for regions in 500m area and register for notification region notification in them. When it reaches one if them, your app is launched in background. Then, re-register for new ones keeping that location at center.

[image]

From [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

> Apps that support background execution may be relaunched by the system to handle incoming events. If an app is terminated for any reason other than the user force quitting it, the system launches the app when one of the following events happens:
>
> For location apps:
>
> - The system receives a location update that meets the app’s configured criteria for delivery.
> - The device entered or exited a registered region. (Regions can be geographic regions or iBeacon regions.)

Answer (score 3):

In case you need location updates frequently but still want to save battery life, try this -

1. Add necessary permissions for using location in background.
2. Start the updates using `startUpdatingLocation`
3. Start deferring updates when in background using `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:` Specify time and distance filters in this method.
4. Make sure you read the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:) and specify all the properties correctly to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution is to use background mode with CoreLocation.  If your app requires iOS 8, the system will relaunch your app, even if force quit by the user.  This is documented in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7):

> In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force
>   quit by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and
>   later are relaunched after being force quit by the user. In other
>   cases, though, the user must launch the app explicitly or reboot the
>   device before the app can be launched automatically into the
>   background by the system.

Answer (score 1):

in iOS 8 they are new steps that we need to pay attention to in order make make the location fetching work. The first step is to add either one or two keys into the project’s .plist depending on the main functionality of the app. The two keys are NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, you will then need to add a String that explains to the user why does the app needs to access his location, something among the lines of “This app uses location in the background/foreground because of A, B and C”. Each of these Strings has a corresponding authorization method that needs to be called, WhenInUse or Alway (i.e. Background).

```
- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500; // meters

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my current experience, you have 3 options to make this work. The first one is to have a silent notification which requires an effort done by the backend. The silent notification is some sort of a push notification but it notifies your app without an alert. The second solution is background fetches. Background fetches don't require a backend solution but sadly you can't control the intervals needed to instantiate it. The third one is having a scheduled local notifications with no messages.

Comment: Ah I was assuming Moves was doing some silent notifications so I turned off notifications for the app and it was still able to pretty accurately retrieve where I've been throughout the day with it being terminated. Does turning off the notifications prevent the silent or empty notifications from occurring?

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure. Did your try the `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`?

Comment: when an app is killed from app switcher.. is it possible to relaunch the app by using the silent notification...

Comment: if an app is killed you can't wake it using a silent notification

Comment: If the app is terminated you can wake it up using silent notification provided it already has a defferred location update pending :)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> Tracking the User’s Location
>
> There are several ways to track the user’s location in the background,
>   most of which do not actually require your app to run continuously in
>   the background:
>
> ```
> The significant-change location service (Recommended)
>
> Foreground-only location services
>
> Background location services
> ```

[Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

And for the details - [Getting the User’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1)

Comment: This doesn't explain how the 'moves' app can track the users location very accurately even when the app is killed.

Comment: Killed as in process terminated manually by the user? Other than accessing the phones location data file and looking for timestamps (doubt this available on non jailbroken systems), the process cannot monitor the location itself.

Comment: The app 'Moves' does it.