# How do I send data to server when device power on in iOS using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, background-process

Now I am developed an application that have to send current location to server for trigger a notification to users when he/she approached the shop.And the problem is when user start device at the first time my app doesn't run thus it can't send the current location to server. How do I do this task?

What I want to know is how to call some function in the app when device started.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background user location when app is terminated/suspended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790893/background-user-location-when-app-is-terminated-suspended)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37248870/3747974