# Location not updated when user killed the application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

How can i resumed the location update when app is killed from app switcher of iphone ?
MyApp working fine in Foreground and background.
But whenever user killed the app, the location updated get stop.

i  set  "locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true " because i want to update the location when user is moving not when user is steady.
and  also i set all the location desired accuracy depend on user speed.

Same i debug in Xcode's simulator,
i added gpx file in my project.
**Start location update in foreground and location is updating-> working fine**

**now move the app in background and location is updating -> working fine**

**now i killed the app from app switcher of simulator and location is updating -> working fine in simulator but not in actual device.**

Whenever user killed the app, the location update get stop in actual device. Is there any way to resume the app for location update when user killed the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background user location when app is terminated/suspended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790893/background-user-location-when-app-is-terminated-suspended)